# Connecting Couchbase Server to elasticsearch fails due to the Authentication

Tags: docker, authentication, elasticsearch, couchbase

I am bringing up Elasticsearch in the docker container and configured Couchbase server also in the docker container. 
both of the services are on the same network in the docker-compose file so there is no **networking** issue in between but an **authentication** issue:

As it's mentioned in the [Couchbase transport plugin](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/elasticsearch-transport-couchbase) for Elasticsearch, I added the user pass for the Couchbase in the elasticsearch.yml file.

```
FROM sebp/elk:564
ENV ES_HOME /opt/elasticsearch
WORKDIR ${ES_HOME}
RUN CONF_DIR=/etc/elasticsearch gosu elasticsearch bin/elasticsearch-plugin install https://github.com/couchbaselabs/elasticsearch-transport-couchbase/releases/download/3.0.1-cypress/elasticsearch-transport-couchbase-3.0.1-cypress-es5.6.4.zip
RUN echo "couchbase.password: password" >> config/elasticsearch.yml
RUN echo "couchbase.username: Administrator" >> config/elasticsearch.yml
```

The problem arises when I want to push data from Couchserver to the elk, by XCDR replication:

- **I use the same user/pass when I configure XCDR in the Couchbase**
- **User/Pass are appended to the elasticsearch.yml**

But as I tested it seems the plugin does not read the elasticsearch.yml, because when I bring up Elasticsearch as a service on the host, this problem is not appearing.

Does anybody knows how is the elasticsearch.yml acts in the docker container or how to totally get rid of authentication in the Couchbase?

This also the Dockerfile of Couchbase :

```
FROM couchbase/server
COPY configure-node.sh /opt/couchbase
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/opt/couchbase/configure-node.sh"]
CMD ["/opt/couchbase/configure-node.sh"]
```

Comment: What version of Couchbase Server are you using?

Comment: Enterprise Edition 5.1.0 build 5552, I updated and added couchbase Dockerfile as well